# How do I make some column, behind a particular cell, of a row shift up (Particular cell is empty)

Tags: excel, vba

so after I empty whatever is in these cells:

```
ElseIf ExistingTeamComboBox <> UpdateTeamComboBox Then
    FoundCell.Offset(0, 0).Value = ""
    FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
    FoundCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
    FoundCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = ""
```

I need the remaining data behind these cells to move forward so that there's no space in between data. How do I do that, is there a way I can shift up these columns only?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Range.Delete method instead of the cell value = "".  See below:

```
Range(FoundCell.Offset(0, 0), FoundCell.Offset(0, 4)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: Thankyou! But there's an error. " FoundCell.Offset(0, 0) = <Object Variable or With block not set>" @legendjr

Comment: I assume FoundCell is set somewhere else in your code.  Assuming it is defined as a Range, you could just do FoundCell.